# Can you make damage with a Grappling attack?

Tags: savage-worlds

A shaken character that is shaken again takes a wound (extras are just taken out) as long as the second shaken result comes from a physical attack of some kind (not a Test of Wills or other maneuver).

When a character grapples another character with a raise, the defender is shaken. As this is a physical attack, can this produce a wound?

Answer (score 5):

### No

The rule says (SWD, p73):

> Grappling is an opposed Fighting roll **that causes no damage**. If
>   the attacker wins, he’s entangled his foe. With a raise, his foe is
>   also Shaken.

Of course, the attacker may attempt to damage their victim in subsequent rounds as long as the defender is still grappled/entangled.